# Resolving errors in Spring EntityManager query using Join on UNNESTed data

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm attempting to treat some input data as a table and execute a Join on it using Hibernate. The goal is to take in 2 lists of UUIDs (as lists of Strings) that are of equal size, treat them as a table with 2 columns, where the uuid pairs are in the same order as they were in the input lists, and then join those values with another table. The query is:

```
var uuidsListOne = // list of Strings
var uuidsListTwo = // list of Strings

String query =
    """
    SELECT *
    FROM the_db_table AS some_table
        JOIN ROWS FROM (UNNEST(ARRAY[?1], ARRAY[?2]) AS (a varchar, b varchar)) 
        WITH ORDINALITY AS m(first_uuid, second_uuid, idx)
            ON cast(some_table.first_uuid AS uuid) = cast(m.first_uuid AS uuid) AND cast(some_table.second_uuid AS uuid) = cast(m.second_uuid AS uuid);
    """;

    return entityManager.createNativeQuery(query)
            .setParameter(1, uuidsListOne)
            .setParameter(2, uuidsListTwo)
            .getResultList();
```

This query (and several other variations on it) runs correctly when executed directly in the PostgreSQL (v12.13) console, but fails when when run via Spring's EntityManager. I've gotten several different errors, depending on which variation of the query I tried, but the error for this query is:
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"`.

If I change the second line of the query to `JOIN ROWS FROM (UNNEST(ARRAY[?1], ARRAY[?2]) AS (a varchar, b varchar))`, then I get the error: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function unnest(record[], record[]) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Any tips on how to get this query to play nice with JPA?

Comment: you can not use prepared statements that way you need to use string replacement

Comment: The change you describe doesn't make sense to me.  Please post both queries in full